# How can a systemverilog process suspend itself?

Tags: system-verilog

LRM indicates process::suspend() can suspend either its own execution or that of another. So I tried following code:

```
module top();
   int cnt = 0;
   process job[$];
  
  initial begin
    for ( int j = 1; j <= 5; j++ ) begin
        do_n_way ();
    end 
     check_status();
  end

  task do_n_way( ); 
    fork 
      automatic int k = cnt;
      begin
        job.push_back( process::self);
        proc(k);
      end 
    join_none 
    cnt++;
  endtask 
  
  task check_status();
    #5;
    foreach(job[i]) begin
      $display("proc %0d state = %0s", i , job[i].status);
    end 
  endtask
  
  task proc( int idx);
    $display("proc %0d before suspend", idx);
    wait (job[idx] != null);
    job[idx].suspend(); 
    $display("proc %0d status here %0s", idx, job[idx].status);
  endtask 

endmodule : top
```

this is output

```
proc 0 before suspend
proc 0 status here RUNNING
proc 1 before suspend
proc 1 status here RUNNING
proc 2 before suspend
proc 2 status here RUNNING
proc 3 before suspend
proc 3 status here RUNNING
proc 4 before suspend
proc 4 status here RUNNING
proc 0 state = FINISHED
proc 1 state = FINISHED
proc 2 state = FINISHED
proc 3 state = FINISHED
proc 4 state = FINISHED
```

I was expecting "state = SUSPENDED" and second display() in tasks proc() not to be printed at all. But, it seem like proc()'s never got suspended. Can someone correct where I am wrong?

Comment: 4 different results on 4 different simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/mTCX).  Can you create a more meaningful example?  Generally speaking, time should elapse when you do something in tasks.  What is the practical use of suspending all processes in the same time step as when they start?

Comment: I ran with VCS on edaplayground. I just wanted to test out suspend() but yes there should be time consuming part before and after suspend() in proc. Indeed, code didn't work because of it.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is one problem with your code. You declared `task proc` with a static lifetime, so its input argument `idx` also has a static lifetime. Even though you went to the trouble of declaring `k` within an automatic lifetime, that prevents the task from being reentrant.

The main problem is the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) is unclear about using `suspend()` to block itself, as well as at what point the process actually gets suspended. It's possible with the code that you have that the process actually finishes before it has a chance to suspend itself. This is a [recently fixed issue](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=3890) in the next revision of the LRM. It now says that `suspend()` does not return until the process actually gets suspended.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out re-entrant issue. Would it help if these tasks are inside a class instead?

It is indeed as you mentioned, processes got terminated before they got suspended. I added some delay after suspend() call in task proc and got the result i was expecting. May I assume that original code will work when suspend() become blocking in next version of LRM?

Comment: class methods in classes always have automatic lifetimes. Your code should work as expected as soon as all tools comply with the next revision.